# Finding a simple template within a 3D point cloud

Tags: 3d

I want to find a template - defined by 5 coplanar, non-collinear points - within a point cloud of say 100 3D points, in the most efficient way possible.

I know there is the ICP (Iterative Closest Point) algorithm for these types of problems but I am unsure if it's the best way to go for a template with such few points.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by a "template"?  Are you just trying to fit a plane (or some other shape) to your "cloud" of 100 points?

Comment: The template is basically a cloud of 5 coplanar, non-collinear points in a rigid geometric configuration